# Objective-C BOOL pointer condition check

Tags: objective-c, pointers, boolean

I get strange behavior on if-checking a BOOL variable. The execution is always entering 'if (wasViewHidden)' condition. No matter if wasViewHidden == NO; no matter how i check it. What i do wrong?

The code pretty much explains itself

```
- (void)onButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    BOOL wasViewHidden;
    [self showHideView:&wasViewHidden];
    if (wasViewHidden) {
        // Always entering.

        // (lldb) p wasViewHidden
        // (BOOL) $0 = NO
    }
}

- (void)showHideView:(BOOL *)previousState
{
    static BOOL isHidden = YES;
    if (previousState)
        *previousState = isHidden;

    // show or hide the view

    isHidden = !isHidden;
}
```

**UPDATE** **(SOLVED)**

thanks to all the commenters. I learned that the code is if fact correct (and theres nothing wrong with my head yet). After xcode restart -> clean -> rebuild it worked correctly - as Leo Natan suggested.

Comment: Oops. A strange problem. Is this perhaps on Xcode 6? Could it be it didn't build properly and is actually executing old code? I saw this in my project. Try clean & rebuild.

Comment: `wasViewHidden` is not initialized to any default so isn't the result unpredictable?

Comment: @Anna But there is an assignment in the method which gives an alternating value? Also, under ARC, I think variables are automatically initialized.

Comment: @LeoNatan, I think auto initialization in ARC is only for objects.  The showHideView method only assigns a value `if (previousState)` otherwise it is not assigned.

Comment: @Anna I made the same oops reading that if statement. It tests that the pointer is not NULL, not if the value is true or false.

Comment: Yep, ran the code and it worked correctly.

Comment: @LeoNatan, You're right, since it's checking it the pointer is not null, it's irrelevant whether the variable is initialized or not.

Comment: I suspect that it's simply that `wasViewHidden` is uninitialized.  Instance variables and (in ARC) object pointers are zeroed automatically, but I don't believe that ordinary scalar locals are.

Comment: How you determine that you are always entering if-statement? You don't have code there. Add NSLog at least inside.

Comment: @HotLicks the value is initialized. If i initialize explicitly, i get the same result.

Comment: @LeoNatan xcode 5. I'm sure i had used such code before, and it worked...

Comment: @Cy-4AH i determine that it enters if-statement because the code inside that statement is executed each time.

Comment: Insert NSLog statements.